# Parse a string which is HTML input

Tags: c#, parsing

Is there an elegant way to get lat and lon values from this string using C#? Thanks.
String is like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="myinput" id="myinput" value='{"lat":11.111111,"lon":22.222222}'>
```

Comment: Depends on your definition of elegant. Immediately my first though is just use a Regex.

Comment: @Brandon [Regex why not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Steve Sure. He's not matching tags though. He could overkill the everliving out of it and use a parser as mentioned in your link. 6 in one.....

Comment: Can someone say how I can parse it with code? Thanks.

Comment: Try HtmlAgilityPack, see this SO link [HtmlAgilityPack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, this is how I'd do it. I'm not claiming to be awesome at Regex by any means. There's probably a better way.

```
var r = new Regex(@"""lat"":(?<lat>\d+\.\d+),""lon"":(?<lon>\d+\.\d+)");
var m = r.Match(@"<input type=""hidden"" name=""myinput"" id=""myinput"" value='{""lat"":11.111111,""lon"":22.222222}'>");
if ( m.Success )
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.Groups["lat"]);
    Console.WriteLine(f.Groups["lon"]);
}
```